# cant get Image or Texture of UI.Image in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures

`m_Image = GetComponent<Image>();`[i am trying to put a list of images and whenever clicked i want to replace clicked image to a plain . as i am a beginner in unity please share your thoughts,,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLMpH.png)

[As shown here the pen image should be replaced in the floor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Pxkw.png)

Comment: welcome to SO. you might want to edit your question, please see [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should use

```
GetComponent<Image>().sprite
```

and set a sprite instead of an Image.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Sprite instead of an image(sprite is a part of images components in unity)

```
GetComponent<Image>().sprite;
```

Read more about Sprites
[Unity Manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Sprites.html)

Comment: cool i got it and it was helpfull